# Is there a way to upload blob url image to imgur?

Tags: javascript, imgur

I try to upload the image to imgur by api via javascript.

I used the base64 code first, but I think the storage is too big.

I changed the type of the file to blob.

but the post request status is 400.

```
data:{
error: "Invalid URL ("blob:http//...")",
method: "POST",
request: "/3/image"
}
```

or

```
data:{
    error: "Invalid URL (Array)",
    method: "POST",
    request: "/3/image"
    }
```

as following my code:

```
async dataCallBack(file){
    //file = "blob http..."
    var imageFile = new File([file], "giftpack.jpg");
    let response = await imgurPost(imageFile); //or file
    console.log(response);
    const result = response.data.data;
    const link = result.link;
    this.setState({url: link});
  }

imgurPost(file){
  return axios.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
  {
    image: file,
    type: 'URL',
    album: '0gECV',
  }
  ,
  {
    headers:{
      'Authorization': 'Client-ID {{clientId}}',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {{accessToken}}'
    }
  }).catch(e=>{
    console.log(e.response);
  })
}
```

Is there the way to use blob type?

Answer (score 0):

A blob URL only works locally (and temporarily), so you can't send a blob with that.

You can use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', file);
fd.append('type', 'URL');
fd.append('album', '0gECV');
```

(You can find examples of using `FormData` with your specific XHR helper elsewhere.)